# function or associated item not found in `parachain_info::Pallet<Runtime>`

Tags: polkadot, parachain, cumulus

I referred to parachain_info normally, but couldn't call his `get` method

```
  717 |             Parachain(ParachainInfo::get().into())
      |                                      ^^^ function or associated item not found in `parachain_info::Pallet<Runtime>`
```

this is my config about `parachain_info`:

`runtime/Cargo.toml`:

```
...
[dependencies]
...
parachain-info = { git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus', branch = 'polkadot-v0.9.16', default-features = false }
...

[features]
default = [
    "std",
]
std = [
...
    "parachain-info/std",
...
```

`runtime/src/lib.rs`:

```
...
impl parachain_info::Config for Runtime {}
...
construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Runtime where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic,
    {
...
        ParachainInfo: parachain_info::{Pallet, Storage, Config} = 3,
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is trying to access the Pallet struct directly while what you want to do is access a value *within* the pallet.
If you e.g. check the [parachain template here](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template/blob/200d26e5e2c1be0eed3f2b75d8d33c76c048db3b/runtime/src/lib.rs#L391) it calls `parachain_id` which is what you are probably interested in.

```
parameter_types! {
    pub Ancestry: MultiLocation = Parachain(ParachainInfo::parachain_id().into()).into();
}
```

Comment: I do solve it this way now, but I think other people can use it this way, but I can't.
https://github.com/AcalaNetwork/Acala/blob/master/runtime/acala/src/lib.rs#L1796